# Nodejs doesn't serve static woff files

Tags: node.js, express

This is my app setup with express server 4.13.4:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, '../public/visitele.ico')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false, limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../static')));
```

Image files in static folder are served perfectly. But when browser requests WOFF file, browser sometimes never finishes request:

[image]

(the other two WOFFs are served correctly). All files are in the right folders. Why may this happen?